# Kentico to Craft

Tags: migration

We’re evaluating the option of migrating our website, which currently runs on Kentico webforms, to Craft.

Do you know of tools and services which make this easier than a re-build?

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about Craft is everything is up to you. So there's not really going to be a service to effectively move from one CMS to another (unless you hire a [Craft partner](https://craftcms.com/partners) for example which is probably the closet thing to a service).

However, if the site is relatively simple and you want to keep the existing design intact, and just re-manage the existing content in Craft, you can absolutely do that.

I would do a CSV export from Kentico of the content you want and use a tool like [Feed Me](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/) to import the content into Craft.

Unlike other CMS that force their own markup on you, you can actually reuse all of Kentico's markup and styles right in Craft. Long-term you'll probably want to move away from that but in the short term, it's totally possible.

You can literally take the output of one of your interior pages from Kentico and copy that into a [Twig](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html) template. Remove that page's specific stuff (the stuff that the CMS inserts in), and use some Twig tags to re-output the parts where needed—for example, `{{ entry.body }}`, `{{entry.title}}`, etc.

Every page in that section could then share the same template. Rinse and repeat with other sections of your site.

That's a very contrived example but it shows you don't need to reinvent the wheel for a migration. Again, it really depends on how you have your Kentico site setup but some people make migrations out to be a bigger issue than necessary.